# What are the particular properties of png image in web development

Tags: asp.net, image, png, devexpress

I am using DevExpress Image and there is a property "IsPng" that will indicate whether this in an png image or not so i am curious how does it matter if it is png image or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main feature PNG features over other "web" image formats is that PNG support [alpha-transparency](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngintro.html).

> "Also known as a mask channel, an
>   alpha channel is simply a way to
>   associate variable transparency with
>   an image. Whereas GIF supports simple
>   binary transparency--any given pixel
>   can be either fully transparent or
>   fully opaque--PNG allows up to 254
>   levels of partial transparency in
>   between for "normal" images (or 65,534
>   levels for the special "deeply insane"
>   formats, but here we're concentrating
>   on image depths that are useful on the
>   Web)."

See http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-DataRep.html#DR.Alpha-channel

This means you can overlay PNGs over other images and text and allow them to "show through" at variable degrees of transparency. You can view some W3C tests at http://www.w3.org/Graphics/PNG/inline-alpha.html